# how can I align the tablecolumn to the middle?

Tags: html, css

I have a nested table and at the moment it looks like the second column of the nested table with docInfo class is aligned more to the top than in the middle. It contains 'John'. The rest of the table looks alright:

```
<table class="strategies">
    <thead>

    <tr>
        <th  class="first_single">Your spending and savings.
        </th>
        <th class="second"></th>
        <th class="fourth">Road</th>

        <th class="fifth_single"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-class="'odd'" class="odd">
        <td>
            <table class="docInfo">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" class=""><img src="/concierge/images/doc7.png" alt="docimage"></td>
                    <td>John</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span><p>Mar 6,2015 9:10:11 AM
                    </p></span></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </td>
        <td>Selected</td>
        <td><img src="/concierge/images/rb_unchecked.png" alt="radiobutton" ng-click="changeStatus(strategy,'selected',1)"
                 ng-show="strategy.statuses[0].status!='selected'" class=""><img src="/concierge/images/rb_checked.png"
                                                                                 alt="radiobutton"
                                                                                 ng-show="strategy.statuses[0].status=='selected'"
                                                                                 class="ng-hide"></td>
        <td><img src="/concierge/images/rb_unchecked.png" alt="radiobutton" ng-click="changeStatus(strategy,'selected',2)"
                 ng-show="strategy.statuses[1].status!='selected' &amp;&amp; persons.length == 2" class="ng-hide"><img
                src="/concierge/images/rb_checked.png" alt="radiobutton" ng-show="strategy.statuses[1].status=='selected'"
                class="ng-hide"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-class="'odd'" class="odd">
        <td>
            <table class="docInfo">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" class=""><img src="/concierge/images/doc7.png" alt="docimage"></td>
                    <td>Bert</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span><p>Mar 6,2015 9:10:11 AM
                    </p></span></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </td>
        <td>Selected</td>
        <td><img src="/concierge/images/rb_unchecked.png" alt="radiobutton" ng-click="changeStatus(strategy,'selected',1)"
                 ng-show="strategy.statuses[0].status!='selected'" class=""><img src="/concierge/images/rb_checked.png"
                                                                                 alt="radiobutton"
                                                                                 ng-show="strategy.statuses[0].status=='selected'"
                                                                                 class="ng-hide"></td>
        <td><img src="/concierge/images/rb_unchecked.png" alt="radiobutton" ng-click="changeStatus(strategy,'selected',2)"
                 ng-show="strategy.statuses[1].status!='selected' &amp;&amp; persons.length == 2" class="ng-hide"><img
                src="/concierge/images/rb_checked.png" alt="radiobutton" ng-show="strategy.statuses[1].status=='selected'"
                class="ng-hide"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

This is the stylesheet:

```
.strategies {
    margin-top: 20px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.strategies td {
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.strategies thead tr {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 14px;
}
.strategies thead th {
    padding: 12px 8px 7px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
.strategies tbody tr {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.strategies tbody tr.odd {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.strategies tbody tr.even {
    background-color: grey;
    color: black;
}

.strategies .first {
    width: 40%;
}

.strategies .first_single {
    width: 69%;
}

.strategies .second {
    width: 30%;
}

.strategies .third {
    width: 20%;
}

.strategies .fourth {
    width: 20%;
}

.strategies .fifth {
    width: 20%;
}

.strategies .fifth_single {
    width: 1%;
}

.docInfo {
    table-layout: fixed;
    float: left;
}
.docInfo th, .docInfo td {
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    line-height: 0.2;
    font-size: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.docInfo .first {
    width: 40%;
}
.docInfo .second {
    width: 60%;
}
.docInfo img {
    background: transparent;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle reference:http://jsfiddle.net/dnpcps4n/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, there is not so much to do. First, you will have to be consistent when you declare :

```
<td>John</td>
```

and

```
<td><span><p>Mar 6,2015 9:10:11 AM</p></span></td>
```

Putting the date in a `<p>` tag will trigger the appearance of margins (top and bottom) from the user agent stylesheet, in other words from the browser. Because the firstname is not in a `<p>` tag, this will mess up your vertical centering as the two table rows will have different heights. So **1) make the two rows have the same height**. I suggest removing the `<p>` tag as it's not made for that. If you need margins you can add css styles instead.

From that point, you are almost done. In your `.docInfo th, .docInfo td` declaration, you need to remove that rule :

```
line-height: 0.2;
```

*To sum up :*

1) Replace `<td><span><p>*date*</p></span></td>` with `<td>*date*</td>` to be consistent with the firstname

2) Remove `line-height: 0.2`

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnpcps4n/13/)